# Template for button with icon and text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, binding

I have problem with creating template for button with icon (created from Path) and text. I would like to set text, icon and foreground when defining the button. I have not working code below. The problem is how to define the binding and then how to set values (icon, text and foreground, background is working).

Template:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="sciDefaultIconButton" TargetType="Button" >
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="backgroundElement" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentWithIcon}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentWithIcon">
        <DockPanel>
            <Path Data="{Binding Icon}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Fill="{Binding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Scienion.Core.UI.Dialogs.LoginDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
Height="195" Width="265">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="260">
        <Button x:Name="BtnExample" Template="{StaticResource sciDefaultIconButton}" Text="Hello" Icon="{StaticResource SomePath}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: As a note, by replacing the Template of the Button you loose all the default visual states for MouseOver, Pressed, Focused etc. Is that really what you want? Maybe you just want to set the Button's Content to combination of Path and TextBlock?

Comment: Custom style is also defined for buttons (also with actions), but thank you for warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Height="28" Click="RefreshGit" Margin="0,2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80">
        <Image Source="Images/Refresh.png" Width="24"/>
        <Label>Refresh</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

[image]
[image]

You can use font awsome SVG like below if you don't want PNG format:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Github" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
    <TextBlock Padding="10,0">GIT</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want because text and icon is not defined in template. The icon is defined using Path/SVG and I need to change also the color if icon (Fill).

Comment: Images/Refresh.png , is this what you want? this is not a path?

Comment: I need define icon/text using binding in the template and then apply the template to a button and set these two variables (text, icon). Icon is defined as static resource: `<Geometry x:Key="StopIcon">M 0 0 h 10 v 10 h -10 Z</Geometry>` and I'm able to set in statically in template, but problem is set it using binding.

Comment: You don't have to embed <Geometry> inline, you can use resource to do that. But anyway, this is irrelevant to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a control to handle displaying Xaml Path icons and an associated text caption

```
public enum CaptionPosition { None, ToLeftOfIcon, AboveIcon, ToRightOfIcon, BelowIcon }

public enum IconSize { ExtraSmall, Small, Medium, Large, ExtraLarge, ExtraExtraLarge }

public class perXamlIconHost : Control
{
    static perXamlIconHost()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(perXamlIconHost), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(perXamlIconHost)));
    }

    public FrameworkElement XamlIcon
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)GetValue(XamlIconProperty);
        set => SetValue(XamlIconProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XamlIconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("XamlIcon", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IconSize IconSize
    {
        get => (IconSize)GetValue(IconSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(IconSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconSize", typeof(IconSize), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(IconSize.Medium));

    public string Caption
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
        set => SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public CaptionPosition CaptionPosition
    {
        get => (CaptionPosition)GetValue(CaptionPositionProperty);
        set => SetValue(CaptionPositionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CaptionPosition", typeof(CaptionPosition), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(CaptionPosition.ToRightOfIcon));

    public Brush StandardForeground
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(StandardForegroundProperty);
        set => SetValue(StandardForegroundProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StandardForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StandardForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush StandardHighlight
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(StandardHighlightProperty);
        set => SetValue(StandardHighlightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StandardHighlightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StandardHighlight", typeof(Brush), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));

    public Brush DisabledForeground
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(DisabledForegroundProperty);
        set => SetValue(DisabledForegroundProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisabledForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Silver));

    public Brush DisabledHighlight
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(DisabledHighlightProperty);
        set => SetValue(DisabledHighlightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledHighlightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisabledHighlight", typeof(Brush), typeof(perXamlIconHost), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray));
}

// ==============================================================================================================================================

public class perXamlIconSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        const int defaultSize = 40;

        if (!(value is IconSize))
            return defaultSize;

        var iconSizeValue = (IconSize)value;

        switch (iconSizeValue)
        {
            case IconSize.ExtraSmall:
                return defaultSize / 2;
            case IconSize.Small:
                return defaultSize * 3 / 4;
            case IconSize.Large:
                return defaultSize * 3 / 2;
            case IconSize.ExtraLarge:
                return defaultSize * 2;
            case IconSize.ExtraExtraLarge:
                return defaultSize * 5 / 2;
            default:
                return defaultSize;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:perXamlIconHost}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:perXamlIconHost}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <ctrl:perXamlIconSizeConverter x:Key="IconSizeConverter" />
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--  Set the DataContext to "self" so that the Xaml Icon item can bind to the Foreground and BorderBrush properties  -->
                    <ContentControl
                        x:Name="PART_IconPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding IconSize,
                                                Converter={StaticResource IconSizeConverter}}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding IconSize,
                                                 Converter={StaticResource IconSizeConverter}}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding StandardHighlight}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding XamlIcon}"
                        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        Focusable="False"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding StandardForeground}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="PART_CaptionTextBlock"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="8,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding StandardForeground}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisabledForeground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_IconPresenter" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisabledHighlight}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_IconPresenter" Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisabledForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="CaptionPosition" Value="None">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="CaptionPosition" Value="ToLeftOfIcon">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="CaptionPosition" Value="AboveIcon">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="CaptionPosition" Value="BelowIcon">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Grid.Row" Value="2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CaptionTextBlock" Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

It supports two colour icons, which bind to the Foreground and BorderBrush properties of the host, and will also change colours to indicate a disabled state.

Icons are defined as a resource (note the pair of move items at the start of each data value to define a common co-ordinate system for the two path objects)

```
<Grid
    x:Key="TestIcon"
    x:Shared="False"
    Background="Transparent">

    <Path
        Data="M 20,35 M 180,210 M 102.6,77.3 C 94.4,77.3 86.7,78.9 79.4,82.0 C 72.1,85.1 65.8,89.3 60.4,94.7 C 55.1,100.1 50.8,106.4 47.7,113.7 C 44.6,120.9 43.0,128.7 43.0,136.9 C 43.0,142.3 43.7,147.6 45.2,152.7 C 46.6,157.8 48.6,162.6 51.2,167.0 C 53.7,171.5 56.8,175.5 60.4,179.1 C 64.1,182.8 68.1,185.9 72.5,188.5 C 76.9,191.1 81.7,193.1 86.8,194.6 C 91.,196.0 97.1,196.7 102.6,196.7 C 108.1,196.7 113.3,196.0 118.4,194.6 C 123.4,193.1 128.1,191.1 132.6,188.5 C 137.0,185.9 141.0,182.8 144.6,179.1 C 148.2,175.5 151.3,171.5 154.0,167.0 C 156.6,162.6 158.6,157.8 160.0,152.7 C 161.4,147.6 162.2,142.3 162.2,136.9 C 162.2,131.4 161.4,126.1 160.0,121.0 C 158.6,116.0 156.6,111.2 154.0,106.8 C151.3,102.4 148.2,98.3 144.6,94.7 C 141.0,91.1 137.0,88.0 132.6,85.4 C 128.1,82.9 123.4,80.9 118.4,79.4 C 113.3,78.0 108.1,77.3 102.6,77.3 z                                                          M 102.6,60.3 C 109.6,60.3 116.4,61.2 122.9,63.0 C 129.5,64.9 135.6,67.4 141.3,70.8 C 146.9,74.1 152.1,78.2 156.8,82.9 C 161.5,87.5 165.5,92.7 168.8,98.4 C172.1,104.0 174.7,110.1 176.5,116.6 C 178.3,123.2 179.2,129.9 179.2,136.9 C 179.2,143.9 178.3,150.7 176.5,157.2 C 174.7,163.8 172.1,169.9 168.8,175.5 C165.5,181.2 161.5,186.4 156.8,191.1 C 152.1,195.7 146.9,199.7 141.3,203.1 C 135.6,206.4 129.5,209.0 122.9,210.8 C 116.4,212.6 109.6,213.5 102.6,213.5 C 95.6,213.5 88.8,212.6 82.2,210.8 C 75.7,209.0 69.6,206.4 63.9,203.1 C 58.3,199.7 53.1,195.7 48.4,191.1 C 43.7,186.42 39.7,181.2 36.4,175.5 C 33.1,169.9 30.5,163.8 28.7,157.2 C 26.8,150.7 25.9,143.9 25.9,136.9 C 25.9,129.9 26.8,123.2 28.7,116.6 C 30.5,110.1 33.1,104.0 36.4,98.4 C 39.7,92.7 43.7,87.5 48.4,82.9 C 53.1,78.2 58.3,74.1 63.9,70.8 C 69.6,67.4 75.7,64.9 82.2,63.0 C 88.8,61.2 95.6,60.3 102.6,60.3 z"
        Fill="{Binding Foreground, FallbackValue=Cyan}"
        Stretch="Fill" />

    <Path
        Data="M 20,35 M 180,210 M 102.6,89.1 C 104.9,89.1 106.8,89.9 108.3,91.5 C 109.7,93.1 110.5,95.1 110.5,97.5 L 110.5,128.5 L 135.7,128.5 C 138.2,128.5 140.2,129.3 141.8,131.0 C 143.4,132.6 144.2,134.6 144.2,136.9 C 144.2,139.3 143.4,141.4 141.8,143.1 C 140.2,144.9 138.2,145.7 135.7,145.7 L 102.6,145.7 C 100.2,145.7 98.2,144.9 96.6,143.1 C 95.0,141.4 94.2,139.3 94.2,136.9 L 94.2,97.5 C 94.2,95.1 95.0,93.1 96.6,91.5 C 98.2,89.9 100.2,89.1 102.6,89.1 z                                                          M 142.0,35.9 C 145.2,35.9 148.6,36.5 152.0,37.6 C 155.5,38.7 159.1,40.6 162.8,43.2 C 168.6,47.2 172.8,51.4 175.3,56.0 C 177.8,60.5 179.1,65.1 179.1,69.8 C 179.1,72.7 178.6,75.6 177.8,78.5 C 176.9,81.3 175.7,84.2 174.2,87.0 C 170.8,82.2 167.1,77.8 162.9,73.8 C 158.7,69.7 154.1,66.2 149.2,63.1 C 144.3,60.0 139.1,57.4 133.5,55.3 C 127.9,53.2 122.2,51.6 116.3,50.6 C 119.6,46.1 123.5,42.6 127.8,39.9 C 132.1,37.2 136.8,35.9 142.0,35.9 z                                                     M 58.7,35.8 C 64.0,35.8 68.8,37.2 73.2,40.0 C 77.6,42.9 81.5,46.6 84.8,51.3 C 79.0,52.5 73.3,54.3 67.9,56.7 C 62.4,59.0 57.3,61.9 52.5,65.2 C 47.8,68.6 43.3,72.4 39.3,76.6 C 35.3,80.8 31.7,85.3 28.6,90.3 C 26.3,87.0 24.6,83.7 23.4,80.3 C 22.2,76.8 21.6,73.4 21.6,69.9 C21.6,65.1 22.9,60.5 25.4,56.0 C 27.9,51.4 32.0,47.2 37.7,43.3 C 41.5,40.7 45.1,38.8 48.6,37.6 C 52.1,36.4 55.5,35.8 58.7,35.8 z"
        Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, FallbackValue=Magenta}"
        Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

and used like this

```
<Button Grid.Row="1">
    <vctrl:perXamlIconHost
        Caption="Small / Below"
        CaptionPosition="BelowIcon"
        IconSize="Small"
        XamlIcon="{StaticResource TestIcon}" />
</Button>
```

The same xaml path resource can produce icons of different size by changing the `IconSize` property.

More details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-xaml-icon-host/).

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. This is quite advanced. I wonder if you know how to do it (only simple without icon size and cation position) using DataTemplate. The only problem is how to propagate binding from datatemplate to button itself.